# How to get a user's input in the URL with an else statement when its not using tagsTxt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been tasked with this and can't wrap my head around it. I'm trying to get a user's input to be inserted into the URL maker/search generator below when the tags `tagsTxt` aren't used. So in an else statement?

Something like 
    `else newURL = 'http://search.company.com/#/search/relevance/min-max/min-max/' + 'main/' + inputSearch;
window.open(newURL);
return false;`

This is what we currently use for the tags to URL maker

```
function doSearch(tags) {
var minMaxTxt = tags.reduce(function(t, next) {
    return t + 'min-max/';
}, '');
var tagsTxt = tags.reduce(function(t, next) {
    return t + 'k_' + encodeURIComponent(next) + '-sfe/';
}, '');
var newUrl = 'http://search.company.com/#/search/relevance/min-max/min-max/' + 'main/' + tagsTxt;
window.open(newUrl);
return false;}
```

The textarea id is `inputSearch`

thanks everyone

Comment: I'm not real sure what you have going on here, but you should be able to grab the value of the input by adding the code `var srch=document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;` followed by `var newUrl = 'http://search.company.com/#/search/relevance/min-max/min-max/' + 'main/' + tagsTxt + srch;`

Comment: Can that be an else statement? I have a search bar, when you search it generates a URL. I want to be able to have both options, how can I add your code and have both?

Comment: What do you mean "both options"?  When a user inputs a value into the textbox to search, do you want to ignore your tags array?  or include your tags array and search input value?

Comment: So for the tags, the user need to press "enter" or "," for it to make a tag and then you can add a tag, and it'll search the tag. I want a user to be able to search for the input value even if they're not in a tag. Sorry I know it's a little confusing

Comment: Thanks.  See if the answer below gets you where you need to be.  It checks to see if there is a value in the textbox and if so searches using the value.  If no value, then you can manipulate the url with your tags code.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin -

I really needed more context to help, but based on what you have shared, I hope this helps:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<button onclick="goPress()">
   Go
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var txtSearch = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
var tags = ["tagA", "tagB"];
const SearchURL = "http://search.company.com/#/search/relevance/min-max/min-max/main/";

function goPress() {
   if(txtSearch && txtSearch.value) { //CHECK TO SEE IF VALUE ENTERED INTO TEXTBOX
     doSearch(txtSearch.value);
   }
   else
     doSearch();
}

function doSearch(input) {
    input = input || null; 
    if (input != null)
       window.open(SearchURL + encodeURIComponent(input)); 
    else {
       //NO VALUE ENTERED INTO SEARCH TEXTBOX
       //HANDLE YOUR TAGS MANIPULATION HERE 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i'll try it out and hopefully I can get this working. This makes sense though, so :fingerscrossed: